# Proving an operator is invertible and find inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, operator-theory

I been having trouble with the following question. This is a homework problem, so I just ned a bit of a push in the right direction.

Suppose we have $E_1=\{f\in C^1([0,1])\,|\,f(0)=0\}$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)+\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f'(x)
$$
And $E_2=C([0,1])$ with the usual norm. Then, prove the operator $A$ given by
$$
(Af)(x)=f'(x)-f(x)
$$
is invertible.

Firstly, the space isn't Banach, so that rules out using a lot of the powerful theorems that I've learnt. To prove invertibility, the only way forward I can see is demonstrating the inequality
$$||Af||\geq m||f||$$
For some $m>0$. However, I'm having trouble working around the supremums to get this to work.
Then, to find the inverse, I've been told I should use the integrating factor method to solve the ODE. I haven't taken any applied math courses and know nothing about ODEs, so I'm struggling to see how to apply this to solve for the inverse operator. Some help here would be fantastic.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to explicitly find the inverse in the end anyway, to show that exists, we might as well first assume it exists, find an explicit formula and then check that that formula is a bounded linear operator.

This leaves us wanting to solve the ODE
$$f' - f = g$$
for $g \in C([0,1])$ with inital condition $f(0) = 0$.

You are told that using an integrating factor might be helpful. Even the  [wikipedia page for integrating factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)  outlines how to use them to solve first order linear ODEs. Applying what is written there, you will find that
$$f(t) = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s} g(s) ds.$$

So define $B: E_2 \to E_1$ by $Bg(t) = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s} g(s) ds$. Then you can check that $B$ is bounded and an inverse to $A$.

Comment: Thanks! This all makes sense now, I was having trouble linking the concepts of operators and ODEs.